# Is there a way to create a String from utf16 array in swift?

Tags: string, swift, arrays

We know that String.utf16 provides the codeunits or String.unicodeScalars provides the scalars.

If we manipulate the codeunits and unicodeScales by removing some elements etc. is there a way to construct back the resulting string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update for Swift 2.1:**

You can create a `String` from an array of UTF-16 characters
with the

```
public init(utf16CodeUnits: UnsafePointer<unichar>, count: Int)
```

initializer. Example:

```
let str = "H€llo "

// String to UTF16 array:
let utf16array = Array(str.utf16)
print(utf16array)
// Output: [72, 8364, 108, 108, 111, 32, 55357, 56836]

// UTF16 array to string:
let str2 = String(utf16CodeUnits: utf16array, count: utf16array.count)
print(str2)
// H€llo
```

---

*Previous answer:*

There is nothing "built-in" (as far as I know), but you can use the `UTF16` struct
which provides a `decode()` method:

```
extension String {

    init?(utf16chars:[UInt16]) {
        var str = ""
        var generator = utf16chars.generate()
        var utf16 : UTF16 = UTF16()
        var done = false
        while !done {
            let r = utf16.decode(&generator)
            switch (r) {
            case .EmptyInput:
                done = true
            case let .Result(val):
                str.append(Character(val))
            case .Error:
                return nil
            }
        }
        self = str
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let str = "H€llo "

// String to UTF16 array:
let utf16array = Array(str.utf16)
print(utf16array)
// Output: [72, 8364, 108, 108, 111, 32, 55357, 56836]

// UTF16 array to string:
if let str2 = String(utf16chars: utf16array) {
    print(str2)
    // Output: H€llo 
}
```

Slightly more *generic*, you could define a method that creates a string
from an array (or any sequence) of code points, using a given codec:

```
extension String {
    init?<S : SequenceType, C : UnicodeCodecType where S.Generator.Element == C.CodeUnit>
        (codeUnits : S, var codec : C) {
        var str = ""
        var generator = codeUnits.generate()
        var done = false
        while !done {
            let r = codec.decode(&generator)
            switch (r) {
            case .EmptyInput:
                done = true
            case let .Result(val):
                str.append(Character(val))
            case .Error:
                return nil
            }
        }
        self = str
    }
}
```

Then the conversion from UTF16 is done as

```
if let str2a = String(codeUnits: utf16array, codec: UTF16()) {
    print(str2a)
}
```

---

Here is another possible solution. While the previous methods are "pure Swift", this one uses the Foundation framework and the automatic
bridging between `NSString` and Swift `String`:

```
extension String {

    init?(utf16chars:[UInt16]) {
        let data = NSData(bytes: utf16chars, length: utf16chars.count * sizeof(UInt16))
        if let ns = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding) {
            self = ns as String
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while !done` part is one of the few times I’ve found labelled breaks useful in Swift i.e. `end: while true … case .EmptyInput: break end`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as simple as:

```
/// An array of the UTF-16 for "Hello, world!".
let a: [UTF16.CodeUnit] = Array("Hello, world!".utf16)

/// A string representation of a, interpreted as UTF-16
let s = String(decoding: a, as: UTF16.self) // <=== The API you want
print(s)
```

Comment: or simply `String(utf16CodeUnits: a, count: a.count)`

Comment: That one requires Foundation, uses an unsafe API, and doesn't generalize to other collections and encodings

Comment: Well the question is **Is there a way to create a String from utf16 array in swift?**. Import Foundation shouldn't be a problem in most situations

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
extension String {
    static func fromUTF16Chars(utf16s:UInt16[]) -> String {
        var str = ""
        for var i = 0; i < utf16s.count; i++ {
            let hi = Int(utf16s[i])
            switch hi {
            case 0xD800...0xDBFF:
                let lo = Int(utf16s[++i])
                let us = 0x10000
                    + (hi - 0xD800)*0x400 + (lo - 0xDC00)
                str += Character(UnicodeScalar(us))
            default:
                str += Character(UnicodeScalar(hi))
            }
        }
        return str
    }
}

let str = "aαあaαあ"
var utf16cs = UInt16[]()
for utf16c in str.utf16 {
    utf16cs += utf16c
}
let str2 = String.fromUTF16Chars(utf16cs)
assert(str2 == str)
println(str2)
```