# How to convert Character to UInt8 in Swift

Tags: swift

I've got an array of Characters in swift:

```
static let charArray: [Character] = [ "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

And I'd like to do some bitwise operations on each `Character` as a byte (`UInt8`).  How do I convert `charArray[0]` to `UInt8`, for example?

Comment: UInt8 is just 8 bits. That won't hold most characters. Limiting to US-ASCII is fine for your usecase?

Comment: @Leo Dabus this isn't a duplicate because I'm trying to convert a Character not a string.

Comment: @Thilo Yeah it's fine, just letters of the alphabet.

Comment: String is just a sequence of characters.I can reopen it if you would like to

Comment: More appropriate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character

Comment: @Leo Dabus It's up to you, but I guess the only way anyone knows so far is to convert it to a string anyway.  Maybe a better answer will come around.

Comment: @Thilo that is closer, but doesn't convert to a UInt8

Comment: That's just because it won't fit into a UInt8 for most characters. But you can convert to codepoint and see if it is small enough.

Comment: Well I guess its a question of use case at this point, whether you need it as a UInt8.  I'm trying to convert some Objective C to Swift.  Thanks

Comment: @JBaczuk you might take a look at this one also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079948/2303865

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to go via the `String` representation of the `Character`:s to convert to `UInt8`. You needn't, however, explicitly initialize an array in your `[Character] -> [UInt8]` conversion; since `String.UTF8View` (from `String.utf8`) is a `CollectionType`, you can apply a `map` operation on the `String.UTF8View` itself; with an `UInt8` initialization. I.e.,

```
let charArray: [Character] = [ "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
let asUInt8Array = String(charArray).utf8.map{ UInt8($0) }

print(asUInt8Array)
/* [83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103] */

print(asUInt8Array.dynamicType)
/* Array<UInt8> */
```

---

With regard to your comment below (*"frustrated over the abstraction of Swift, as compared to the simple ways of Objective-C"*): if you believe the above to be messy, you could include it in an extension to `SequenceType` constrained to `Character` elements, allowing easier use in practice. E.g.:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Character {

    /* extension accessible as function */
    func asByteArray() -> [UInt8] {
        return String(self).utf8.map{UInt8($0)}
    }

    /* or, as @LeoDabus pointed out below (thanks!),
       use a computed property for this simple case  */
    var byteArray : [UInt8] {
        return String(self).utf8.map{UInt8($0)}
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let charArray: [Character] = [ "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]

/* use extension function */
let asUInt8Array = charArray.asByteArray()

/* or computed property */
let asUInt8Array = charArray.byteArray
```

Comment: This is frustrating how abstracted Swift is.  This is very simple in Objective-C.

Comment: @JBaczuk I'm not well-versed with Obj-C, but generally, as a language focuses on "being safe", some "limitations" will end up making its way into the language, as compared to a less safe but _possibly_ (in some cases) more versatile language, w.r.t. somewhat low-level operations. However, with Swifts versatility of allowing extensions to native types, you can easily create your own wrappers to simplify what you consider non-simple code. As an example, I'll add a version of the solution above using an extension to `SequenceType` with `Generator.Element`:s constrained to `Character` type.

Comment: That would make it more simple sure, good answer just frustrated with Swift, that's all.  It's only "swift" for certain things.

Comment: @dfri when extending any method if all you need to pass to that method is the element itself you can use a computed property ex. `var bytesArray: [UInt8] { return ... }`

Comment: @LeoDabus You're right, since we're not doing any throwing or such, a computed property would be more suitable above, thanks! (Will include in answer when not on a mobile device).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to convert a Character to UTF-8, but a String has a `utf8` property, so you could use the following:

```
let charArray: [Character] = [ "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
let string = Array(String(charArray).utf8)
print(string)
```

Comment: That's an idea that does work, there must be a better way.

Comment: You are aware that a Character might be more than one UTF-8 byte?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
var char: Character = "a"
var byte: UInt8 = Array(String(char).utf8)[0]
```

There must be a better way...

Comment: I thought so, too. This seems to do the trick: `char.asciiValue!` or `"a".utf8.first!`.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

```
let charArray: [Character] = [ "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]

var oneAscii: UInt8 = charArray[0].asciiValue!
```

Of course, if your input isn't a literal from the ASCII set, you want to be making sure the result isn't nil.

Comment: This is risky, as the forced unwrap can cause the app to crash, especially if the source of the characters is developers control.

Comment: True, I'm just showing a simple example of the solution, not the carefully checked version I'd actually use. In my case, I'm using a literal, so I know it works. If the input range could fail, one needs to check things... I'll add a warning.

Answer (score 0):

To improve @dfri answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025104/1979882

for **Swift 3** you have to use this:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Character {

    /* extension accessible as function */
    func asByteArray() -> [UInt8] {
        return String(self).utf8.map{UInt8($0)}
    }

    /* or, as @LeoDabus pointed out below (thanks!),
     use a computed property for this simple case  */
    var byteArray : [UInt8] {
        return String(self).utf8.map{UInt8($0)}
    }
}
```