# Add a custom init method to Array of specific type in swift

Tags: swift, generics, initialization

I'd like to add a custom `init` method to the `Array` class in swift using an extension, but the key is I'd like to add it only to arrays of bytes (`UInt8`)

I've currently got something like this:

```
public class MyData {
}

public func toByteArray(myData: MyData) -> [UInt8]? { // a global function
    // code to check if myData is valid, and extract byte array
}
```

It seems like the more "swifty" thing to do is use a failable initializer, so I'd like to write it like this

```
extension Array where Element : UInt8 {
    init?(myData: MyData) {
        // code to check if myData is valid, and extract byte array
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile though, I get `Type 'Element' constrained to a non-protocol type 'UInt8'`

I've found [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672403/234) where you don't extend Array, you instead extend _ArrayType, but this doesn't seem it'll work for initializers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079948/2303865

Comment: How would you use such an extended array type ?   let  a = Array<UInt8>(myData: yourData) seems worst than your toByteArray() function.  Or perhaps you should just give that function a more meaningful name such as  UInt8Array(myData:)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is Swift 2.2 is to make a protocol that UInt8 conforms to and use it into the Array extension as a constraint.

```
protocol UInt8Protocol {}
extension UInt8 : UInt8Protocol {}

extension Array where Element : UInt8Protocol {

    init?(myData: MyData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Into the Swift evolution list it is mentioned that, this (constrained extension using a same-type constraint) is a highly-requested feature. It might be part of one of the next versions of Swift.